# Not able to open Safari finder programatically in React using ref

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, safari

I have to make the first async call which generally takes 1.5 secs to 2 secs, and after that, I want to open mac Finder to upload images.

But it's not getting open just because of security reasons.

Please see the below GitHub page

Note-> It's working in chrome but not working in safari.

https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/issues/1009

You can refer to code sandbox code for reproducing the issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/async-file-uploader-kdt8d8

how I can solve this issue.
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.